# gcc can't find header file

Tags: c++, gcc

I have this main in a project in c++ but I can't compile it in gcc due to this error:

```
In file included from main.cpp:11:
../framework/application.h:8:10: fatal error: includes.h: El fitxer o directori no existeix
    8 | #include "includes.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
```

What it says is that the file "includes.h" doesn't exist. It exist but is in another directory and I don't know how to compile using a header from another directory.

I tried:

```
gcc -I ../framework/ main.cpp 
gcc -I../framework/ main.cpp
gcc -I "../framework/" main.cpp
```

Comment: Where is the `framework` folder compared to `main.cpp`?

Comment: `includes.h` is supposed to be in the same folder as `application.h`. And it is supposed to be found without providing additional include paths.

Comment: @drescherjm in the directory src there's 2 directories one is main and the other is framework, the main is in the directory main but the includes.h is in framework

Comment: @user7860670 I know but gcc should have a option to call files from another directories

Answer (score 1):

Testing on my machine with a similar directory structure using the I directive worked for me. Ensure that your path is correct and I would even try using an absolute path as a test.

Comment: Can I see the terminal line you used? perhaps could be a hint for me, thank you

Comment: Could you show me your directory structure in this format: `/ test.cpp test2.cpp /frameworks includes.h includes.cpp`. The single slash being the root of the project.