# CMake: Some include directories defined in source files, but undefined in headers for nested target

Tags: c++, cmake, g++, c++20, msys2

Given the following project structure:

```
.
└── library/
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── include/
    │   └── class1.hpp
    ├── src/
    │   └── class1.cpp
    ├── build/
    │   ├── _deps/
    │   │   └── fmt-build
    │   └── sample/
    │       └── app_using_library.exe
    └── sample/
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── main.cpp
```

CMakeLists.txt of library:

```
project(library)

include(FetchContent)

FetchContent_Declare(
        fmt
        URL https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt/releases/download/9.1.0/fmt-9.1.0.zip
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(fmt)

add_library(library STATIC 
  "src/class1.cpp" 
  "include/class1.hpp" 
target_include_directories(library PUBLIC include)
target_link_libraries(library PRIVATE fmt::fmt)
```

CMakeLists.txt of app_using_library:

```
project(app_using_library)
add_executable(app_using_library main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(app_using_library PRIVATE library)
```

class1.hpp:

`#include "fmt/core.h" // cannot open source file "fmt/core.h"`

class1.cpp:

`#include "fmt/core.h" // works fine`

Is there a possible cause or explanation for why the fmt headers are includable in class1.cpp, but not in class1.hpp when building both `library` and `app_using_library`? The include works correctly in the header when just building `library`

The compiler couldn't find the fmt headers in "class1.hpp", but it could find them in "class1.cpp".

The full error:

```
  FAILED: sample/CMakeFiles/app_using_library.dir/main.cpp.obj 
  C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe  -ID:/Programming/cpp/library/include -g -std=gnu++20 -MD -MT sample/CMakeFiles/app_using_library.dir/main.cpp.obj -MF sample\CMakeFiles\app_using_library.dir\main.cpp.obj.d -o sample/CMakeFiles/app_using_library.dir/main.cpp.obj -c D:/Programming/cpp/library/sample/main.cpp
  In file included from D:/Programming/cpp/library/sample/main.cpp:2:
  D:/Programming/cpp/library/include/class1.hpp:4:10: fatal error: fmt/core.h: No such file or directory
      4 | #include "fmt/core.h"
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
  compilation terminated.
```

Comment: `#include "fmt/core.h"` should work when you build the library `library`. That is, it should work whenever you include it directly in `class1.cpp` or when you include in `class1.hpp` but when compile `class1.cpp` (or `class2.cpp`). Please, show (add to the question post) the **complete** error message, which describes include "chain" and the source file which is currently compiled. You could find example of such complete message e.g. in [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65670152/gcc-cant-find-header-file).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I've added the error message. I've also added that the include error only occurs when compiling the executable target, to which `library` is linked. Could perhaps the strange reversed project hierarchy be to blame?

Comment: You use `PRIVATE` keyword for link with the `fmt` library: `target_link_libraries(library PRIVATE fmt::fmt)`. This keyword means that only `library` will get properties (like include directories) from the `fmt::fmt` target, but consumers of `library` won't get these properties. So why do you expect the executable `app_using_library`, which is consumer of `library`, to get include directories from `fmt`? If you want properties from `fmt::ftm` to be propagated **both** to `library` and its consumers, then use PUBLIC keyword.

Comment: "I've also added that the include error only occurs when compiling the executable target, to which `library` is linked" - Next time, please, add all details when **ask the question**. The less we should **guess** about your **real situation**, the higher chance you will get the answer, which is applicable for your case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'll remember that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I don't want the `fmt::fmt` target to be available in `app_using_library`. I just want it to be available in the headers of `library`, and I want `library` to be available to `app_using_library`. Compiling `library` works fine, but when I try to build `app_using_library` suddenly `#include "fmt/core.h"` stops working in the headers of `library` are not found anymore.

Comment: "I just want it to be available in the headers of `library`" - Compiling doesn't work in a way you want. Include directories are passed to the compiler when it compiles a single **source file** (with `.cpp` extension). It is impossible to say to a compiler: "Hey, this include directory should be used only when you parse that **header file** but not others." Because of that, CMake allows you to tie include directories only for source files, but not for the header files.

Comment: There is a notion about library's **public header**: that header is intended to be available to the consumers of the library. E.g., `class1.hpp` is *public header* for your `library`. For make a header available to the consumers, the header should be located in the PUBLIC include directory of your library. Any **header included by a public header is public** by yourself.  E.g., since `class1.hpp` is a *public header* of the `library` and includes `fmt/core.h`, then `fmt/core.h` is a *public header* for your library too. And you need to make this headers accessible via PUBLIC include directory.

Comment: @Tsyvarev So if I were to include `fmt/core.h` only in a **private header** of the library, does that mean that it wouldn't be necessary for `app_using_library` to link to fmt::fmt anymore?

Comment: If you use `fmt/core.h` only in the private headers of your `library`, then your current code should work: `library` is PRIVATE linked with `fmt::fmt`, `app_using_library` is linked with `library`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks. Could you perhaps post your last 2 comments as an answer, so I could mark it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565974/cmake-some-include-directories-defined-in-source-files-but-undefined-in-header#comment131630142_74565974) from Tsyarev in the comments:

Such includes should only be done in private headers, i.e. headers not included in the `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` for that target. This prevents any executable target using `library` from also having to link to the library included in public headers.

Tsyarev's [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74565974/cmake-some-include-directories-defined-in-source-files-but-undefined-in-header#comment131630142_74565974):

> There is a notion about library's public header: that header is intended to be available to the consumers of the library. E.g., class1.hpp is public header for your library. For make a header available to the consumers, the header should be located in the PUBLIC include directory of your library. Any header included by a public header is public by yourself. E.g., since class1.hpp is a public header of the library and includes fmt/core.h, then fmt/core.h is a public header for your library too. And you need to make this headers accessible via PUBLIC include directory.

> If you use fmt/core.h only in the private headers of your library, then your current code should work: library is PRIVATE linked with fmt::fmt, app_using_library is linked with library.

Answer (score 0):

It fails while compiling "app_using_library" because only "library" knows about fmt.
To resolve that you need to also include the information you have defined about fmt into the app_using_library CMakeLists.txt

Comment: Is it necessary for `app_using_library` to define the `fmt::fmt` target if only `library` needs to include headers from FMT?

Comment: Yes, because you are using the header file from `library` which contains a `#include` from fmt. When compiling `app_using_library` it reads the header from `library` and in doing so also tries to include everything the `library` header is including.